# Django print in template all arugment passed from view

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like fast for debug purpose be able to print all the argument passed from view to template is there some magic templatetag, which can do the job saving my time for writing in curly brackets all the name explicitly?

UPDATE:

I found `{% debug %}` but it print much more than needed can it be somehow filtered?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Django Debug Toolbar?

You can install it for development and see the template context which will show you what you need.

It also has plenty of other useful tools.

https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar